# JSON object from java ObjectName.toString

Tags: java, android, json, maven, jackson

I have a java object witch generates this output when i type objectName.toString() :

```
Bus [id=1, nextStationID=0, previousStationID=0]
```

Is there a JSON parser that lets me make a JSON from the string that my object generates?
something like: `JsonObject x = new JsonObject(busObject.toString())`

It is important for me to generate it from the string that i get when calling the .toString method.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: google Gson can be used

Comment: Can you pls give me an example how? I read the documentation a little bit and i didn't see anything mentioning .toString

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/ this should help

Comment: It is not what I am looking for. Please read more carefully the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed my problem by overriding my toString() and printing directly a json object

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("{\"id\" :");
            builder.append(id);
            builder.append(", \"latitude\" :");
            builder.append(latitude);
            builder.append(", \"longitude\" :");
            builder.append(longitude);
            builder.append("}");
        return builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

A JSON parser's goal is to make a JSON string from an Object or to create an Object from a JSON string.

In your own answer, manually making a JSON string from your Object is ok but I think that using a JSON parser will make your code easiest to maintain and more efficient.

You can use this toString() method :

```
public String toString() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(this, Bus.class);
}
```

With this solution, even if you remove or add fields in your class, the toString() method still be ok.

To finish, if you want to convert your object to a JSONObject, I advise you to create a method like `toJSONObject` and to manually make the conversion inside it.

Comment: Yes, i agree it is harder to maintain, but if i use your code, my application will crash since i use jpa and it enters in a loop because of the references.

Comment: Ok. I refactored the code of your answer and so I didn't see any loop references in it ;) Happy you found a solution anyway.

Comment: This looks like it could work and I don't need to maintain it myself.

Answer (score 3):

i know that this is old, but it is available to create you own json format in toString method. (Eclipse)

Step 1. Right click in edit and go to Source (Alt+Shift+S) -> And click 'Generate toString...'

Step 2. Click edit (as shown in picture)
[Edit to String method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtGiK.png)

Step 3. Create new Template

Step 4. Paste this line: ${object.className}":{"${member.name()}":"${member.value}", "${otherMembers}"}

Step 5. Click ok and apply changes.

Hope this helps anybody. So this way is simpler and faster, you do not have to use gson or any other json parser.